# Get src type of img or video tag (not extension)?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have an image tag such as this:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

I know I can get the src by using `myImageEl.src`.

However, how do I get the type of the src (`.gif` in this case)?

Basically, my end goal is to pass the file type to `window.URL.createObjectUrl()`

```
let src = imageEl.src;
let srcType = src.type; // Here I need to get the type
let videoFile = new Blob([src], {type: srcType});
let videoSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoFile);
```

Comment: you can use some sort of regex or maybe `src.split('.')` and then get the last index of the resulting array, which will be the type of file - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7sf4z3b9/ - actually the duplicate link at the top is better, it uses `.split('.').pop()`

Comment: Are you asking how to grab `.gif` from `smiley.gif`?

Comment: Do you want the file type or the extension?

Comment: file type @LucaKiebel

Comment: Really the only reliable way to get the actual type is to fetch the resource and see what it really is. I can change the name of a `.jpg` file to `.png` but that doesn't change the actual contents.

Comment: You can't really get the file type from the name, you'd need to make a request and look at the headers in the response to determine what the MIME type is

Comment: basically you can get the file type as `let fileType = (/[.]/.exec(filename)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : undefined;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgSrc = 'image.jpeg';
var ext = imgSrc.replace(/^.*\./, '')
```

I am not very good with regex, but using regex to fetch the extension of the image or video is the a good way of accomplishing this task.

For precision sake you could compare ext with a predeifined set of array

```
imgTag = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
vidTag = ['mp4', '3gp']
```

then you can compare using a forEach loop

Answer (score 0):

From your tags I noticed you want to access image source type from javascript, if so you can use following codes base on what attributes we have for that image element:
for example if image element has id :

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById(id);
var imgsrc = imageElement.src;
var imgType = imgsrc.split('.').pop();
```

imgType will be the type of your image.

And if your image element doesn't have id, you can use document.getElementsByTagName("img") instead of document.getElementById(id) and code will look like this

```
var imageElement = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imgsrc = imageElement.src;
var imgType = imgsrc.split('.').pop();
```